# How to check convergence given a metric

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

let $\mathbf{B}$ denote the set of bounded sequences in $\mathbb{R}$

if a= $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and b= $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are elements of $\mathbf{B}$ and we have:

$d_{\infty}(a,b) = sup\{|a_n - b_n| : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

let $u(m,n)_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbf{B}$ and let $v(n)$ be an element of $\mathbf{B}$.

How do I check that

(1)
$u(m,n)$ converges to v(n) with respect to the metric $d_{\infty} $

$\iff$

(2)
$u(m,n)$ converges uniformely to $v(n)$?

(I think I've solved $2 \to 1$ but I have a problem with associating the corresponding $m\geqslant M$-values needed for uniform convergence when going from $1 \to 2$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform convergence of {$u_n^m$}$_{n=1}^\infty$ to {$v_n$}$_{n=1}^\infty$ means that for every $\epsilon>0$ exists $N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $m\geq N(\epsilon)$, and for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|u_n^m-v_n|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

This is equivelant to saying that for every $m\geq N(\epsilon)$ we have $sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|u_n^m-v_n|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$.

Which by the definition you gave is equivelant to the statement that for every every $m\geq N(\epsilon)$ we have $d_\infty (u_n^m,v_n)<\epsilon$.

It's simply from the fact that uniform convergence means that $sup_{x \in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$.